# Diferentes opacidades usando SSRPass en Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

he estado usando `SSRPass` y me di cuenta de que todos los objetos (mallas) reflejan en igual cantidad.

```
const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);

const ssrPass = new SSRPass({renderer, scene, camera});
ssrPass.opacity = .1; // ajusto el reflejo

composer.addPass(ssrPass);
```

*El resto de código es muy extenso por lo cual no lo incluiré todo*

Con ese código ya tengo para que todos las mallas en la escena reflejen su entorno, pero como hago para que cada uno refleje de forma distinta?

Por ejemplo si tengo un espejo, debería reflejar mucho más que un simple metal...